# I want to update multiple rows which are selected through checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

Am selecting rows via checkbox through this loop applied on select query.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    $res = $row['userid'];
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='$res'></td>";

   echo 
    "<td>ID :{$row['userid']}  <br> </td>".
    "<td>ID :{$row['id']}  <br> </td>".
    "<td>{$row['name']}  <br> </td>".
    "<td>{$row['shifttime']}  <br> </td></tr>";
      $i++;    
   }
```

Then want to update my db through the id's am getting from checkboxes

```
 if(isset($_POST['chk'])){
    $shift=$_POST['shiftTime'];
    $chkarray = $_POST['chk'];
    foreach ($chkarray as $val) {
    $sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime ='$shift' WHERE id='" . $_POST["chk"] . "' ";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);
```

Thanks.

Comment: So - your problem is?

Comment: My db is not getting updated values

Comment: Because `$_POST["chk"]` in a query `$sql` is `array`?

Comment: i have also tried using id='$val';

Comment: You can use WHERE id IN ($_POST['chk']), without executing any loop.

Comment: for example i have selected 10 rows so it will also work for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql in query -

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime = $shift WHERE id IN $_POST['chk'] ";
```

Yo don't need to execute loop.

Comment: then it will work for several rows as well ? in case if have selected 10 rows ?

Comment: i tried using 
this `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk' value='$res'></td>";`
and also `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='$res'></td>";`
`$val = implode(",", $_POST["chk"]);
$sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime = $shift WHERE id IN (" . $val . ") ";
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);`
but still it doesn't work

Comment: print your query statement and share, is this showing any mysql error?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$_POST["chk"]` is array and you should use `IN` operator.

Don't use `foreach` This code should work.

```
$vals = implode(",", $_POST["chk"]);
$sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime ='$shift' WHERE id IN (" . $vals . ")";
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);
```

EDIT :
As you told you want to use `foreach`, which in fact not recommended as  it will use multiple query to update. Still here is a code snippet which should work.

```
if(isset($_POST['chk'])){
    $shift = $_POST['shiftTime'];
    $chkarray = $_POST['chk'];
    foreach ($chkarray as $val) {
        $sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime ='" . $shift . "' WHERE id= '" . $val . "'";
        $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='$res'></td>";
i have already used chk[] so it will get the values in array ? i dont have to use implode ?

Comment: No, you have to use `implode`, Because in the query, `IN` operator will not support `Array`. it will take multiple items separated by `comma` which `implode` does before the query.

Comment: `$vals = implode(",", $_POST["chk"]);
$sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime = $shift WHERE id IN (" . $vals . ") ";
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);`
i used it but it doesn't work.

Comment: am testing it live so its not executing the page.

Comment: The query seems fine to execute and update the required rows. So, unless I see what error you are getting, its difficult to say whats need to be done!

Comment: I have updated my answer with `foreach`. But not recommended!

Comment: i have tried both methods, still doesn't work i can not understand whats the problem.
using `foreach` atleast code is getting the id's from db but using `IN` the page is not being executed

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['chk'])){`
`$shift=$_POST['shiftTime'];`
`$chkarray = implode(',', $_POST['chk']);`
`echo $shift;`
`echo "<br>$chkarray";`

`$conn = mysql_connect($servername,$database_username,$database_password);`

`$sql = "UPDATE user_shift_test2 SET shifttime ='" . $shift . "' WHERE id IN ('$chkarray')";`
`$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn);`
i also tried this